# How do I show context when searching old messages in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

When I search for messages in Microsoft Teams, if the result is recent Teams will show me messages sent before and after for context. However, if the message is more than a few weeks old, Teams will only show the matching result without any context.

Is there a way to jump back in my conversation history to view context for a message in my search results?